# Why variable is not changing in one line and changing in another?

Tags: python, global

I am stuck in a project in kivy.
Its base problem is this -

```
a = 'a' " with global a is changing here
print('He is '+ a + ' good boy')# but not here
def t():
    global a
    a = 'not a'
t()
print(a)
```

## result

He is a good boy # it is not changing here
not a  # but it is changing here
Ii want it to change even in the line
if this problem is resolved I would be able to resolve the problem.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You print `a` before you changing it. You have to change your variable `a` first before printing to console.

```
def t():
    global a
    a = 'not a'

a = 'a'
t() # here you change your variable
print('He is ' + a + ' good boy') # after changing you can print a
```

Then you're getting this output:

```
He is not a good boy
```